# Swift : How to avoid duplicate entries in CoreData for implementation with JSON array?

Tags: ios, json, swift, uitableview, core-data

I am developing an app in Swift which fetches JSON records from API, converts it into NSArray and reloads in UITableView. 
I need to map the NSArray with CoreData and, when making a new request to API, if there is new child added in JSON response, I've to store only that child in CoreData. I.E. I have to avoid repetition of values of NSArray in CoreData.

I found few solution as "using unique constraint for data models" and "HyperSync and DATAStack" but I am not able to do so. Do I have to implement a module to check through all the records ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your objects in JSON have some identification, e.g. `[ { "id" : 4, ...} ...]`, then you should store these "id" values in your CoreData objects, and try fetching  already existing ones during mapping before creating new ones.

If there is no identification or unique fields in JSON objects, then your task is not resolvable.

E.g. RestKit framework does all that for you automatically, you have to configure only mapping and `identificationAttributes`.

Comment: I want to do it without any Pod installation. As you mentioned I need to  fetch only existing one, how can should I do it. And can you suggest me any good tutorial for RESTKit ? Thanks.

Comment: RestKit is Pod, here there is basic example provided:  https://github.com/RestKit/RestKit

Comment: If you want to do it by yourself, and you have unique identification of JSON objects, then you can store this attribute in some "externalId" property of your ManagedObject. Then, before you create new object, you fetch existing one by condition "externalId = %@", objectJson[@"id"]. If there is no existing objects - then you create new one, otherwise update existing one.